How to Improve Performance of MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline with Atlas Search and Grouping?
I'm using MongoDB Atlas Search index across multiple fields in my collection. I've created an aggregation pipeline with two stages: the first stage performs a keyword search using Atlas Search, and the second stage groups the field values along with their counts. However, I'm experiencing significant performance issues where the second stage takes approximately 50 to 60 seconds to load data.
Below is the aggregation pipeline I'm using:
[
  {
    $search: {
      index: "keyword_search_index",
      queryString: {
        defaultPath: "title",
        query: '((title: ("product") OR description: ("product") OR subdocuments.name: ("product") OR company.name: ("product") OR skills.name: ("product") OR title: ("products") OR description: ("products") OR subdocuments.name: ("products") OR company.name: ("products") OR skills.name: ("products")))'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$subdocuments"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        code: "$subdocuments.code",
        name: "$subdocuments.name"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
]

How can I improve the performance of this aggregation pipeline? Any suggestions or best practices to optimize both the search and grouping stages are highly appreciated.

How did you measure performance to conclude it is $group stage that's slow?

@AlexBlex When I run first stage that gives me result in 2-3 secs but when I run both stages then it takes 55-60 secs. I'm using MongoDBCompass to run the query.

I thought it would be the case. The thing is the first stage alone gave you the first batch of the results. $group is one of the "blocking" stages - it waits for previous stage to return all results before it can progress. It's very likely it's the $search stage that takes that long, and there is no good way around it. If you have that much of data, and have to use full-text search, it's gonna be slow.

@AlexBlex there are not too much data in the table. I have 125,000 records. I think there would be something which is wrong. It should not give issue in this small set of data.

agree, this is quite small. can you try some other blocking stages instead of $group? eg. $sort by $subdocuments.code? is still slow?

Can you share the results you are getting?  How many records are getting matched??

Hi! I am stuck in a similar problem. Did you find any specific solution?

Not yet @PritamUpadhya
